# Composite Builds in Android Studio

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio-2.2

I am looking to use Gradle's new composite build feature in an Android Studio project called MyProject that includes both an Android Archive library (.aar) called DroidLib and a Java library (.jar) called JavaLib. These libraries are currently checked into version control due to my inability to get Gradle to pull dependencies from our internal Artifactory. That is, the DroidLib project has the JavaLib.jar checked into git under the libs folder and the MyProject project has the DroidLib.aar checked into git under its libs folder. I would like to make changes in both DroidLib & JavaLib while debugging and consuming the changes in MyProject w/o manually rebuilding from the dependency projects.

The new Composite build feature in Gradle offers just the thing I need however it looks to be something triggered from the command-line via a flag such like this:

```
--include-build ../DroidLib
```

In the Gradle docs it looks like this flag allows Gradle to override a dependency declared in the local project with a similarly the project declared in the included build. This would make sense since they both would use the same group/name/version scheme. I'm having trouble trying to understand how I would use this from Android Studio where my DroidLib dependency is declared as a local filesystem based dependency:

```
compile(name:'DroidLib-1.19', ext:'aar')
```

How would the command line flag tell Gradle which dependency is overridden since there is no apparent group/name/version declared on DroidLib? Also how could I make use of this in my app launch run config which uses the Gradle-aware make feature? Is there a way to pass add'l options to the Gradle-aware make or am I over-thinking what has to happen here?

Comment: Ooh, unrelated: Is this composite build feature out yet? I just heard about it at Droidcon last weekend, but I thought he said it was a month away.

Comment: I read about it in the official Gradle docs about 1.5 weeks ago. (https://docs.gradle.org/current/release-notes?_ga=1.134684530.2092888033.1440426106) I just naturally assumed it was supported since it's listed there. I haven't actually tried it yet.

Comment: Ah, yes. It looks like a Gradle 3.1 feature so most likely not supported by the Android  SDK yet?

Comment: That's possible? I don't really know, I haven't used it yet, but I'm happy to already see it's on SO. I'm excited to learn about it, and I'll come back to this question when/if I get to use it.

Comment: Yeah, I think I'm a bit premature. I may give it a whirl to try it and report back.

Comment: hey, some years passed. Have you seen any improvements here? I managed to get the other project imported using the `includeBuild` directive in settings.gradle. Now I see the other project (library), but Android Studio does not quite get the linkage. If I use "find Usages" or "go to source", it will decompile instead of finding the class in the library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Short answer

It is not available yet (it is in IntelliJ 2016.3).

### More details

According to [this blog post](https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2016/10/intellij-idea-2016-3-eap-gradle-composite-builds-and-android-studio-2-2/), the feature is in IntelliJ 2016.3:

> With composite builds, everything is much, much simpler. All you have to is to attach the Gradle projects of these libraries via the Add button in the Gradle tool window (my-utils in our case), and then select Compose Build Configuration from the context menu for the original project.

[image]

Unfortunately, according to [this release note](http://tools.android.com/recent/androidstudio23beta1isnowavailable), Android-Studio 2.3 is based on IntelliJ 2016.2. So we'll have to wait for IntelliJ 2016.3 to be merged into Android Studio =/.

Comment: DId anything change here ?

Comment: Yay, I just got it working with Android Studio 3 canary 4 :)

Comment: Yay! Good news!